# How do I chain calls that take blocks as inputs?

Tags: scala

Say I have these declarations:

```
val f1 = EventFilter.info(pattern = s"starting calls: three_step.ps, three_step.ps2, three_step.ps3", occurrences = 1)
val f2 = EventFilter.info(pattern = s"starting calls: three_step.cgrep, three_step.wc", occurrences = 1)
val f = Seq(f1, f2)
```

Right now I can do this:

```
f1.intercept { f2.intercept {
  ... Some code here ...
}}
```

However, I want that first line to be expressed as a function of `val f = Seq(f1, f2)` rather than of `f1` and `f2` directly.  I'm not sure how to express this but I want to be able to do this for any `Seq[EventFilter]` objects

Comment: What is the signature of `intercept`? What is the end result? It would be helpful to work with something that compiles.

Comment: Sounds like you want a `foldMap` with the endofunction monoid

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `intercept` takes in and returns the same type here, since that's the only way to chain functions in this way.

Most generally, you can use a `foldLeft` or `foldRight` to accomplish this sort of chaining.

```
eventFilters.foldLeft(startingValue) { 
    case (acc, next) => next.intercept(acc) 
}
```

You might also be interested in [`Future.chain[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function$@chain[a]%28fs:Seq[a=%3Ea]%29:a=%3Ea), which chains together a sequence of functions `T => T`.  If you would want to use that, you need to make your `Seq[EventFilter]` into a `Seq[Foo => Foo]` (where `Foo` is the parameter/return type of `intercept`):

```
val interceptFuncs = eventFilters.map(_.intercept _) //Seq[Foo => Foo]
Function.chain(interceptFuncs)(startingValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in scalaz:

```
implicit def endofunctionMonoid[A] = new Monoi[Function1[A, A]] {
  def append(f1: Function1[A, A], f2: => Function1[A, A]): Function1[A, A] =
    f1 _ compose f2 _
  def zero: Function1[A, A] = a => a
}
val fs = List(f1, f2) // event filters
fs.foldMap { _.intercept _ } // map the list to Function1s and accumulate via the semigroup operation.
```